APIMS - Ignore OperationNotFound error - prevent logging it into AI
With Azure APIMS I would like to ignore certain errors and prevent them from logging those into Application Insights.
I understand that this can be achieved by creating a policy. However none of the examples I tried worked and the error still get logged into Application Insights.
Sample that did not work for me:
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <!-- Inbound policies go here -->
    </inbound>
    <backend>
        <!-- Backend policies go here -->
    </backend>
    <outbound>
        <!-- Outbound policies go here -->
    </outbound>
    <on-error>
        <choose>
            <when condition="@(context.LastError?.Reason == "OperationNotFound")">
                <!-- Suppress logging for OperationNotFound -->
                <set-variable name="logError" value="false" />
                <!-- Return a custom response -->
                <return-response>
                    <set-status code="404" reason="Not Found" />
                    <set-body>Operation not found.</set-body>
                </return-response>
            </when>
            <otherwise>
                <!-- Default error handling -->
                <return-response>
                    <set-status code="500" reason="Internal Server Error" />
                    <set-body>Internal server error occurred.</set-body>
                </return-response>
            </otherwise>
        </choose>
    </on-error>
</policies>


Please confirm you want to ignore OperationNotFound error and instead log a custom response in app insight?

@IkhtesamAfrin no, that is not correct. I want to prevent logging OperationNotFound into Application Insights.

Yes, you can do that but need to add a custom message instead. I believe its not feasible to prevent it completely like skipping it, you need to log something else instead to come out of the on-error section
